# Is there some limitation of query length in RODBC sqlQuery() function?

Tags: r, database, hive, rodbc

I wonder if there is query length limitation for `sqlQuery` function from `RODBC` package? I can't find any information in documentation but that's my hypothesis.

The thing is that when I use Hive editor to write a query I get correct output for my queries (including the long one). But when I connect through the `sqlQuery()` the long query (~250) doesn't work. I get error:

```
 [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'my long query here'
```

I can't think about different reason why the query works in Hive editor and does not work with `sqlQuery()`.

I know 250 lines is a lot for SQL query but unfortunately I don't have permission to create temporary table in database I work with, so I do it in my code and that's why the code is so long. There's no way I can shorten the code.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: query length shouldn't be a problem here, I successfully run queries of 500 and 700 lines with `sqlQuery`. Error may be caused by some misescaped special characters if you paste your long query directly inside R code. Try to save query in your working directory with name, for example, 'myquery.txt' and then run command in R `result <- sqlQuery(myODBCConnection, paste(readLines("myquery.txt"), collapse = "\n"))`

Comment: I tried pasting as well as saving code in the file, in both cases it doesn't work. I am sure that it is not a problem of special characters.

Comment: Usually `sqlQuery` gives 2 lines of information in case of error like `[1] "HY000 140 [Cloudera][ImpalaODBC] (140) Unsupported query."` and then `[2] [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'select * from etc...'`. In your question you give only the second line of error message, could you share also the first line?

Comment: Can you paste the result of `paste0(sort(unique(strsplit('my long query here', split = "")[[1]])), collapse = "")` in your question?

Comment: As suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26393878/3220769), is it a driver issue?